# when click on the one dropdown other dropdown will be close

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a dropdown list Javascript Toggle method. I face a problem a problem. The problem is -  After clicking one dropdown, another dropdown still opens. I want others dropdown Will to be closed when I click on dropdown. This happen will be each dropdown. How do I do it?

```
<html>
   <head>
       <style>
     nav{
     width:100%;
     height:50px;
     background-color:#000;
     }
     button{
     height:50px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     border:0;
     background-color: transparent;
     color: #fff;
     cursor: pointer;
     }
     div{
     display: none;
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
     position: absolute;
     }
     #myDIV1{
     background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
     color: #fff;
     }
     #myDIV2{
     background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
     color: #000;
     }
     .show{
     display:block;
     }
  </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <nav>
     <button onclick="myFunction1()">Dropdown1</button>
     <button onclick="myFunction2()">Dropdown2</button>
  </nav>
  <div id="myDIV1">
     This Dropdown for Dropdown 1
  </div>
  <div id="myDIV2">
     This Dropdown for dropdown 2
  </div>
  <script>
     function myFunction1() {
        var element = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
        element.classList.toggle("show");
     }
     function myFunction2() {
        var element = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
        element.classList.toggle("show");
     }
  </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this a little easier to scale by using one function for all dropdown menus. This function closes all open drop-downs and toggles the target one.

```
function toggleDropDown(id) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu').forEach(el => el.id === id ? el.classList.toggle('show') : el.classList.remove("show"));
}
```

```js
function toggleDropDown(id) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu').forEach(el => el.id === id ? el.classList.toggle('show') : el.classList.remove("show"));
}
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}

#myDIV1 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  color: #fff;
}

#myDIV2 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  color: #000;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button onclick="toggleDropDown('myDIV1')">Dropdown1</button>
  <button onclick="toggleDropDown('myDIV2')">Dropdown2</button>
</nav>
<div class='dropdown-menu' id="myDIV1">
  This Dropdown for Dropdown 1
</div>
<div class='dropdown-menu' id="myDIV2">
  This Dropdown for dropdown 2
</div>
```

Here is the same thing, but instead of hard-coding click events, it's better practice to use eventListeners, which get applied through the script after the page loads, like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('nav button').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      let id = e.target.dataset.dropdown
      document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu').forEach(el => el.id === id ? el.classList.toggle('show') : el.classList.remove("show"));
    })
  })
})
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('nav button').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      let id = e.target.dataset.dropdown
      document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu').forEach(el => el.id === id ? el.classList.toggle('show') : el.classList.remove("show"));
    })
  })
})
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}

#myDIV1 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  color: #fff;
}

#myDIV2 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  color: #000;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button data-dropdown="myDIV1">Dropdown1</button>
  <button data-dropdown="myDIV2">Dropdown2</button>
</nav>
<div class='dropdown-menu' id="myDIV1">
  This Dropdown for Dropdown 1
</div>
<div class='dropdown-menu' id="myDIV2">
  This Dropdown for dropdown 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution, all the code is commented.

*div1* and *div2* are hidden by default...
so with `.toggle()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle

- I will add the class `.show` **if** there isn't
- **else** I will remove the class from it.

so if the user clicks the first time on the `button` it will show the *div1* then if he reclicked will hide, and this is looped (if he reclick)...

with `classList.remove`,  we will hide the other element (always):

- **if** clicked the `button` N**1** will hide *div2*
- **if** clicked the `button` N**2** will hide *div1*

```js
let div1 = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
let div2 = document.getElementById("myDIV2");

function myFunction1() {
  div1.classList.toggle("show");
  // remove the class for the second div
  div2.classList.remove("show");
}

function myFunction2() {
  div2.classList.toggle("show");
  // remove the class for the first div
  div1.classList.remove("show");
}
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}

#myDIV1 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  color: #fff;
}

#myDIV2 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  color: #000;
}


/* this is the class we add and remove or toggle with javascript*/

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav>
    <button onclick="myFunction1()">Dropdown1</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction2()">Dropdown2</button>
  </nav>

  <!-- 1 -->
  <div id="myDIV1">
    This Dropdown for Dropdown 1
  </div>
  <!-- 2 -->
  <div id="myDIV2">
    This Dropdown for dropdown 2
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation as to how exactly does this answer solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I think that the comments are enough in this case... for you, I need to write that `classList.remove` remove the class (is self-explained in the code and comment)

Comment: @Stranger now I put the explanation